# JavaFx Snapshot of content on hidden Tab

Tags: javafx

I have an application with a TabPane. I want to create a snapshot of all tabs. One would think that tab.getContent().snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null) would work. But that's only the case if the tab had been active before. If not, one gets strange effects and omissions depending on its content. For the HTMLEditor, for example, I get the editor's base UI but without the contained text.

Example Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SnapshotTest extends Application {

    // Create a tab with an html editor
    public Tab createEditorTab(String txt) {
        Tab t = new Tab(txt);
        HTMLEditor e = new HTMLEditor();
        e.setHtmlText(txt);
        t.setContent(e);
        return t; 
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane pane = new TabPane();
        TabPane imagePane = new TabPane();

        Tab snapshotTab = new Tab("Snapshots");
        Button b = new Button("Take Snapshots");
        b.setOnAction((e)-> {
            imagePane.getTabs().clear();
            for (int i=1;i<pane.getTabs().size();i++) {
                Tab t = pane.getTabs().get(i);
                WritableImage imageView = t.getContent().snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
                Tab imageTab = new Tab("Snapshot of "+t.getText());
                ImageView v = new ImageView();
                v.setImage(imageView);
                imageTab.setContent(v);
                imagePane.getTabs().add(imageTab);
            }
        });

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().addAll(b,imagePane);
        snapshotTab.setContent(box);
        pane.getTabs().addAll(snapshotTab,
                createEditorTab("Tab 1"),
                createEditorTab("Tab 2"));
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(pane);
        root.setMinSize(300, 400);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I click on 'Take Snapshots' I get images of the HTMLEditors but without their content.

[image]

Only after I have activated their tabs at least once, does the content show up.

[image]

I was aware that nodes need to be part of a scene before one can take a snapshot, but apparently there is more to it, and if they are part of an inactive tab, there is some rendering step happening only when the tab is shown. Is there a way to force this without requiring each tab to become active?